# How to get values of cells in tmsfmxlivegrid hidden columns?

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey, live, tms

i want to change text color cells in specific column basing on values of other cells in other column using the GetCellLayout event like this.

```
procedure TForm1.TMSFMXLiveGrid1GetCellLayout(Sender: TObject;
      ACol, ARow: Integer; ALayout: TTMSFMXGridCellLayout; ACellState: TCellState);
    begin
      if ACol = 1 then
        if TMSFMXLiveGrid1.Cells[5, ARow] <> '' then
          ALayout.FontFill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    end;
```

the problem is that when the column 5 is not visible in the screen area(you must scroll to see it) the color still black instead of red, because the column 5 is not loaded;
NB:the grid is binded to a dataset.

Comment: Did you try to use `TMSFMXLiveGrid1.BeginUpdate` before all your processes and `TMSFMXLiveGrid1.EndUpdate` at the end of your processes?

Comment: I don't know why use it in this event, i don't think that it's safe in this event.
what i need is to force a non visble column to load value.
(i've resolved the problem by creating a cache and updating it at needs but i want to know how to force the column to load)

Comment: Visual components needed to reload for visual updates. In order to reload them, you should use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`.

Comment: Did you ask TMSSoftware on their support forum? They normally respond within a few hours.